Flutter: Account deletion successful but not logging out
I'm working on a Flutter app and I have implemented account deletion functionality. The issue I'm facing is that after the account is deleted successfully.

{"success":1,"status":203,"message":"Your account has been deleted
successfully."},

but the user remains logged in.
logout process is not being triggered after the account deletion.
Here's the relevant code snippet from my deleteUserAccount function:
      Future<void> deleteUserAccount(
    BuildContext context,
    DeleteAccountProvider deleteAccountProvider,
    UserProvider userProvider,
    SharedPreferences prefs,
  ) async {
    try {
      final confirmed = await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.accountDeletion),
            content: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.sure),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cancel),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.delete),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );

      if (confirmed != null && confirmed) {
        String? userToken = prefs.getString('user_login_token');
        final email = userProvider.user?.email;
        final response = await deleteAccountProvider.deleteAccount(context, userToken ?? '', email ?? '');
        if (response) {
          await logout(prefs);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('An error occurred: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout(SharedPreferences prefs) async {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Language Code After Logout: ${prefs.getString('languageCode')}');
    }

    if (mounted) {
      context.read<UserProvider>().clearUserData();
    }
    await prefs.remove("user_login_token");

    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const OnBoardingScreen(),
        ),
        (route) => false,
      );
    }
  }


Why there are multile shared preference instances? Like you can just create a global instance which can be use anywhere or just in that particular  class. So, try to use only single instance of shared preference for "deleteUserAccount" and "logout". No need to call "await sharedPreference.getInstance" twice.

Thanks for guidance , I know and I will modify it.

I have followed your suggestion, now Kindly tell me how to resolve my issue

Hi, it's unlikely your question will be answered in its current state. This is for several reasons, which are too long to explain here, but more information can be found at the how to ask page. You'll increase the chance of someone being able to answer your question by reading the following  headings at the above link: Search, and research, and Help others reproduce the problem. GL! :)

You have just popped the screen on delete account button pressed. Make a function and write the logging out logic there and call that function on the onpressed event of the Delete account button.
